# Adding a JFrame to a JFrame, force new JFrame to be closed before first can be used again

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jdialog

I'm trying to add a `JFrame` (bar) to a `JFrame` (foo), which would force `bar` to be closed before `foo` can be intergrated with once again.

Such as this, where the "About Eclipse" frame must be closed before I can write code once again:

[image: Example]

Something like this won't do the trick (simplified):

```
JFrame foo = new JFrame("Base");
JFrame bar = new JFrame("About");
foo.add(bar); // IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: This has been asked ***many*** times here and elsewhere. Use a modal JDialog or JOptionPane, not another JFrame. Don't try to add a top level window (JFrame) to another top level window. [The dialog tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) will explain some of the details and the JDialog and [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) APIs will explain the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JDialog like this

```
JFrame foo = new JFrame("Base");
JDialog bar = new JDialog(foo, "About", true);
```